# If $N$ divides $a$ and $N$ divides $b$ then

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> If $N$ divides $a$ and $N$ divides $b$ then $N$ divides $a \cdot b$?

Is the statement true? I mean.

$$a \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$$

$$b \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$$

$$\implies ab \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$$

But I am not sure how rigorous this is?

Comment: It's true, and it's very easy to prove if you use the definition of divisibility. Did you try it? PS: If you want to see it with congruences, this comes from a more general property of congruences that state the following: If $a\equiv c \pmod{N}$ and $b\equiv d \pmod{N}$, then $ab\equiv cd\pmod{N}$, you can try to prove this too!

Comment: But either $N\vert a$ or $N\vert b$ implies $N\vert ab$.

Comment: Good point @FrankScience! So you can even change the "and" in your claim by an "or" @Lebes

Comment: "$N$ divides $a$" means that there exists $k$ such that $kN=a$. Use this and what you want follows at once.

Answer (score 2):

> If $N \mid a$ and $N \mid b$, then $N \mid ab$.

Suppose $N \mid a$ and $N \mid b$, then by the definition of divisibility there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $Nx = a$ and $Ny = b$. So we have that
$$ab = NxNy = N^2xy$$
which is clearly divisibly by $N$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).